# JBoss/Spring-WS times out on processing very large SOAP response

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, spring-ws, jboss6.x

We have a J2EE application running on JBoss EAP 6.0 that consumes SOAP webservices from a third party application. We use Spring-WS to send our request and receive our responses.

For normal and large size responses, the application works perfectly fine. However, on invoking a specific web service (for reporting purposes), a response that is around 250 MB was sent by the third party web service and the java application was not able to process it.The transaction times out and throws a timeout error

Exception trace below:

```
org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceIOException: I/O error: Read timed out; nested exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceIOException: I/O error: Read timed out; nested exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
        at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:502)
        at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:343)
        at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:337)
        at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:329)
```

However, when the response XML was accessed in an offline mode, the application was able to process the file within a minute or two.

So, here are my questions in processing the SOAP response synchronously (i.e. in realtime):

1. Is there any limit on the length of the SOAP response that can
   be handled by the application layer (especially JBoss EAP 6.0) in
   our case
2. By any chance, does Spring-WS enforce any restriction on the
   size of response that can be handled ?

Comment: You should modify your question to include more information about what you mean by "was not able to process it". What kind of error did you get?

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid I can't answer question #1, but I can try to answer #2: Spring-WS does not enforce any restrictions on XML message size. However, it can be problematic to load very large SOAP message in memory, which is what happens when you use a `SaajSoapMessageFactory` (the default). Instead, switch to the [AxiomSoapMessageFactory](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/docs/current/reference/html/common.html#d4e653), and turn off payload caching as described on that page. That way, the entire SOAP message is not loaded in memory.

That said, it looks like you are suffering from read timeouts rather than out of memory errors. You might want to increase the timeout. The easiest way to do that is to switch to the `HttpComponentsMessageSender` and configure the `readTimeout` property on that.

Comment: Thanks for the quick repsonse Arjen.

Comment: It appears only a portion of my comment got sent last time. I have the same configuration which you have advised. i.e. I use AxiomSoapMessageFactory  with payload caching set to false. For timeouts, I use CommonsHttpMessageSender(deprecated) instead of HttpComponentsMessageSender and SoTimeOut has been set. However, we are needing to process responses of > 250 MB (we had a request to process 650 MB response today). After increasing the read timeouts, we are not getting timeout issues, but,the process goes on without completion. Will a batch mode of processing using an offline file be better ?